# mysql order by column within first column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns, distance

is it possible to order within the first column like

select * FROM table where........ order by price desc and distance, distance

```
price holds values
0, 10, 24, 30 ...
and distance are values out of the lon/lat calculation. and now it displays it like this:

    value1(price=30) ... 19,8km
    value2(price=24) ... 8,2km
    value3(price=10) ... 48km
//and then it starts with the entries in which price is 0 with the correct distance order
    value4(price=0) ... 1,20km
    value5(price=0) ... 1,28km
    value6(price=0) ... 2,74km
    and so on...
```

and what i want is, that within the ones where price is > 0 it shall first display them BUT with the distance as order method, then the ones with price = 0 and distance

so basically it should ignore the price value itself, just price > 0 before 0 and order by distance within the price. how could that query look like? thanks for any help :)

so this is what i want it to be;

```
value2(price=24) ... 8,2km
value1(price=30) ... 19,8km
value3(price=10) ... 48km
value4(price=0) ... 1,20km
value5(price=0) ... 1,28km
value6(price=0) ... 2,74km
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

using order by
example
select * from price order by asc
or 
select * from price order by desc

up to you

Comment: well thanks but that is just a normal order by, but i need to order the distance within the price > 0 and then the distance with price = 0

Comment: try visit this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a calculated column to sort on:

```
SELECT *, IF(price > 0, 0, 1) AS pricegtzero FROM table WHERE........ ORDER BY pricegtzero, distance
```